# How do I save an unfinished blog?

Tags: safecracker

I am adding a blog, but I have to attend a meeting. How do I save the blog without actually publishing it to my website. I click on submit and it automatically is published. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Change the status to "closed".

Answer (score 1):

As you've tagged the question with `safecracker` I'm assuming that you are creating your blog entry through a safecracker form on the front end of the site rather than using the control panel.

If this is the case, you will need to expose the `status` of the entry in the `safecracker` form template (or `channel form` from EE 2.7 onwards). Details of how to do can be found in the [channel form docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html#status).

If you have access to the control panel, then, as Jim says above, you need to set the status of the entry to closed. The Status can be found in the Options tab on the Publish page.